# REST возврат MAP в своём объекте

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, rest

Есть REST Controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserRestController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    @PostMapping(value = "/users")
    public List<UserEntity> users() {
        return userService.getAll();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/user/add", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public Result userAdd(Result result, @RequestBody UserEntity user) {
        userService.save(user);
        return result.set(true, "User successfully added!").add("user", user);
    }

}
```

Result:

```
public class Result {

    private boolean status = false;
    private String message = "";

    private Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();

    public Result() { }

    public Result(boolean status, String message) {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void init() { }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public Result set(boolean status, String message) {
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;

        return this;

    }

    public Result add(String key, Object object) {
        data.put(key, object);
        return this;
    }

}
```

В запросе /user/add ответ уходит, но параметра data из Result нет.

Подскажите как сделать что бы он был.

Comment: а что есть в ответе от сервера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас видимо используется библиотека jackson. Добавьте в класс Result метод

```
public Map<String, Object> getData() {
        return data;
}
```

Вот вывод у меня с геттером(что выше):

> {"status":true,"message":"User successfully
>   added!","data":{"user":"Testme"}}

и без него:

> {"status":true,"message":"User successfully added!"}